# How to connect output from PEM fuel cell to Boost Converter?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkPa3.png)

I am trying to connect out of PEM fuel cell to Boost Converter, however the connection seems incompatible. What block or converter should I use?

I tried PS-Simulink converter block but the output was also not connecting to the converter block.